# Video file playback issue

Tags: video-editor, file-formats

I have a 75.7 GB avi file that when viewed only plays ~ 2 seconds of video and then quits.  How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Are you looking to just play the file or edit the file so that it can be played?

Comment: much more info is required, like what media player you are using, if you created the video so you could have a better idea at how its encoded and if you have any additional codecs to play different encode types.

Comment: It was created with a web cam that is motion activated, and i tried to open it in both VLC as well as windows media player.  I would be happy if i can just view the file, editing would make the end result easier but not a must.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any comments on why playback stops after only 2 seconds because you haven't given us much information about what operating system you are working with, what you you are attempting to use to play the video back, etc. When we know that we can give a much more detailed answer.

However, I'd like to make a suggestion that you may be running into problems with the max file size for whatever system you are working with. Especially if your hard drive is formatted in FAT32, you will be unable to work with files that are 4GB or larger.

[This article](http://neuron2.net/LVG/filesize.html) has some good information on the upper bounds of AVI file sizes. From it's suggestions, I recommend finding a tool which will allow you to divide your file into smaller (< 4GB) segments, which will in turn also make them much more manageable for editing or storage.

Comment: Windows 7, VLC or windows media player, created via web cam using Motion Activated Asus Live Utility.  The file is stored on a 2TB NTFS HDD.